# Styling menu bar css

Tags: css

I have a menu bar here: http://jsfiddle.net/Qn3kh/1/
Here is the codes:
CSS:

```
ul#menu {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 1180px;
    height: 35px;
    background-color: rgb(25, 25, 25);
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 2px;
}
#menuborders1{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    top: 6px;
    bottom: 6px;
    border-top: 3px solid rgb(30, 174, 206);
    border-bottom: 3px solid rgb(30, 174, 206);
}
#menuborders2{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    top: 5px;
    bottom: 5px;
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(255, 136, 0);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(255, 136, 0);
}
ul#menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -3px;
}
ul#menu li a {
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Arial;
    padding: 10px 75px 7px 75px;
    color: #fff;
}
ul#menu li.current a {
    color: rgb(25, 25, 25);
    background-color: #1EAECE;
}
ul#menu li a:hover {
    color: rgb(25, 25, 25);
    background-color: #FF8800;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <div id="menuborders1">
    <div id="menuborders2">
        <li class="current"><a href="#" data-id="div1">Description</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-id="div2">Shipping and payment</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-id="div3">Returns</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-id="div4">Feedback</a></li>
    </div>
    </div>
</ul>
```

For me the menu displays like that(normal and hover):
[image]
But I want it to display like that(normal and hover):
[image]

Comment: You are not very clear what you want "like that(normal and hover): enter image description here But I want it to display like that(normal and hover): enter image description here"

Comment: So you just don't want those lines through it?

Comment: Add a black background to each link and you're done. Are you really incapable of at least attempting this yourself?

Comment: Adding black background color doesn't really help because you can see it will make space between the buttons

Comment: On a politer note, your assumption that a space is 3px wide is going to lead to problems. On Chrome/Win8 for example, there is a 1px gap between links. Consider floating the `<li>`s instead

Comment: Adding black background to the button doesn't help because you can see some space between each button, as you can see here jsfiddle.net/Qn3kh/2, I WANT this space only on hover

Comment: You should've made that clear in your original question so that all this confusion could be avoided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if i understand, but try add `bakground` to the `a` element. After it looks like your second attached image.

```
ul#menu li a {
  background:black;
}
```

And you must comment spaces between `li` elements:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <div id="menuborders1">
    <div id="menuborders2"><!--
        --><li class="current"><a href="#" data-id="div1">Description</a></li><!--
        --><li><a href="#" data-id="div2">Shipping and payment</a></li><!--
        --><li><a href="#" data-id="div3">Returns</a></li><!--
        --><li><a href="#" data-id="div4">Feedback</a></li><!--
    --></div>
    </div>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Qn3kh/4/

According to @Bojangles :

```
ul#menu{
  font-size: 0;
}
ul#menu li{
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

After is no comment needed.

http://jsfiddle.net/Qn3kh/8/

If you want to achieve the space on `hover`:

```
ul#menu li:not(.current) a:hover{
    color: rgb(25, 25, 25);
    background-color: #FF8800;
    margin: 0px 4px;
}
```

Note: This will move all the elements `1px` to left and `1px` to right.

Comment: That doesn't help because you can see some space between each button, as you can see here http://jsfiddle.net/Qn3kh/2/, I WANT this space only on hover

Comment: Using comments like that is horrible. You should either float the `<li>`s or use the `font-size: 0` trick

Comment: Almost done it, I only need one thing, just to add the same space that was before between the buttons ONHOVER(remember your old reply? I want the same little space between the buttons only on hover)

Comment: Can you please help me with that?

Comment: Sure, `:hover{margin: 0px 1px;}`

Comment: In your case `4px` add just `1px` space. ` :hover{margin: 0px 4px;}`

Comment: I'm confused, where should I add `:hover{margin: 0px 1px;}`?