# menu bar on active and on hover

Tags: css, hover

I have this menu bar: http://jsfiddle.net/Qn3kh/1/
Codes:
Css:

```
ul#menu {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 1180px;
    height: 35px;
    background-color: rgb(25, 25, 25);
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 2px;
}
#menuborders1{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    top: 6px;
    bottom: 6px;
    border-top: 3px solid rgb(30, 174, 206);
    border-bottom: 3px solid rgb(30, 174, 206);
}
#menuborders2{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    top: 5px;
    bottom: 5px;
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(255, 136, 0);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(255, 136, 0);
}
ul#menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -3px;
}
ul#menu li a {
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Arial;
    padding: 10px 75px 7px 75px;
    color: #fff;
}
ul#menu li.current a {
    color: rgb(25, 25, 25);
    background-color: #1EAECE;
}
ul#menu li a:hover {
    color: rgb(25, 25, 25);
    background-color: #FF8800;
}
```

Html:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <div id="menuborders1">
    <div id="menuborders2">
        <li class="current"><a href="#" data-id="div1">Description</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-id="div2">Shipping and payment</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-id="div3">Returns</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-id="div4">Feedback</a></li>
    </div>
    </div>
</ul>
```

You can see that when hover on the active button the css change to the :hover style, I want it to do not change, the active button got its style and the hover got its style

Comment: why are you posting same ques multiple times. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18227561/styling-menu-bar-css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Qn3kh/3/

Updated the css:

```
ul#menu li:not(.current) a:hover{
    color: rgb(25, 25, 25);
    background-color: #FF8800;
}
```

instead of

```
ul#menu li a:hover{
    color: rgb(25, 25, 25);
    background-color: #FF8800;
}
```

Comment: Just a note to self to keep in mind when using the above css. :not is not compatible with older browser. Great and neat solution nonetheless

Answer (score 1):

There's your answer buddy :)

http://jsfiddle.net/Qn3kh/6/

Added the following css:

```
ul#menu li.current a,
ul#menu li.current a:hover{
    color: rgb(25, 25, 25);
    background-color: #1EAECE;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, is that solution better? `ul#menu li:not(.current) a:hover` or yours?

Comment: It is a good solution for modern browsers but :not will not work in older browser. In older browsers, what I suggested will work as well. @arbitter's is a good solution nonetheless